# What is the name of a part that is placed between drawer tracks and the cabinet wall for a narrower drawer?

Tags: cabinets, drawers

I've seen these pieces that look a bit like plastic cubes that were used as in the question title. There were four of them, two on each side, holding a track for a drawer that was narrower than appropriate for the cabinet.

I'm searching for them online but can't find the right term to search by.

[image]

The tracks are blue, the cabinet is black, and the parts I'm looking for are the gray squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Drawer runner spacer block" seems to work.

[image]

*Google image search results.*

Comment: @ispiro - Try "Drawer Slide Spacer" or "Drawer Side Spacer" on Amazon.

Comment: There are adjustable ones out there, such as the Miller FastBlock... https://www.fastcap.com/product/miller-fastblock

Comment: Last time I needed these I made them from scrap.   Mildly rewarding but not enjoyable and not what I would choose if I had this answer and comments at the time!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use Rail Spacers from IKEA. Part number 110646. Those are round white ones.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHMoV.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).